# doc package: multiple macros with one definition

Tags: documentation, dtx, doc

I'm writing class documentation with the `doc` package (well, via `ltxdoc` documentclass). I have several similar options like font sizes and line spacing, that I want to group together in one `macro` environment, listing the names in a vertical stack at left, where there is usually just one name.

I'm fine to hardcode the number of names to stack (e.g. 3) and leave unused blank, but the definition should be aligned with the first name.

#### MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{macro}{foo}
    the definition of foo
  \end{macro}
  \begin{macro}{bar}
    the definition of bar
  \end{macro}
  % \begin{macros}{foo}{bar}{}
  %   the definition of foo and bar
  % \end{macros}
\end{document}
```

#### Desired output

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use multiple `macro` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{macro}{foo}
\begin{macro}{bar}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{macro}
\end{macro}

\begin{macro}{baz}
  the definition of baz
\end{macro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is this intended behaviour of the `macro` environment? I would not have expected this to work.

Comment: @jessexknight Yes, that's the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could use l3doc instead

```
\documentclass{l3doc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{macro}{foo}
    the definition of foo
  \end{macro}
  \begin{macro}{bar}
    the definition of bar
  \end{macro}
   \begin{macro}{foo,bar}
     the definition of foo and bar
   \end{macro}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to full release of LaTeX3 :) In the mean time, I don't like these "(End definition for ..." and it [seems](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/635) there's no way to disable it, so I prefer egreg's solution for now.